# Why We Have to Use self.rect and self.image to Determine Rect and Surf on Sprites?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm new at pygame, so I don't know so much about sprites. I wanted to make my code more clean so I used a sprite. And to display my image with rect I wrote:

```
    self.frame_index = 0
    self.surf = self.frames[self.frame_index]
    self.frame_rect = self.surf.get_rect(midtop = (self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
```

But it raised AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'image' error. Enemy is my class' name. When I used self.image and self.rect instead of self.surf and self.frame_rect my code worked properly.

My main question is: Why we have to use self.rect and self.image when we use a sprite to determine our surface and rect?

Comment: please provide a [mre], it looks to me that you have not defined `self.image`, also did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main question is: Why we have to use self.rect and self.image when we use a sprite to determine our surface and rect?

This is related to the [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). *Groups* are used to manage *Sprites*. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, center_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)
    
    def update(self, surf):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a]) * 5
        self.rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w]) * 5
        self.rect.clamp_ip(surf.get_rect())

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([Player(window.get_rect().center)])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update(window)

    window.fill(0)
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```